# What is Lo Jong mind training?

Tags: mahayana, tibetan-buddhism

A friend of mine recently mentioned Lo Jong mind training to me, when I asked my teacher he told me not to worry about it.

Would anyone be willing to explain what it is and what it is used for?

Comment: Could you please refine the scope of your question? What is it that you seek to know that can't be found from a web search, or from wikipedia? ex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojong

Comment: But your teacher told you not to worry about it...

Comment: I am more than happy to answer your question since I received transmission of the practice, but it is to general for me to answer. Like Buddho, I would ask you to 'refine the scope of your question' and ask for something you can not find on wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lo= mind, and jong=learn, train, purify. It is a combination of pithy instructions for training the mind on the Buddhist path, particularly for those who have taken bodhisattva vows, but can be used by any practitioner. It trains the mind to awaken compassion for self and others. Rather than dwelling on obstacles, crying mea culpa, one uses them to learn by taking on the suffering of self and others as a training exercise to improve the depth of ones compassion. The steps to mind training together with explanation are too extensive for this forum, however, Jamgon Kontrul's "The Great Path to Awakening" is a good place to find more in depth answers.

Comment: I'd like to encourage this type of answer, I think it's ideal/helpful: it includes an answer or summary in your own words, plus a reference for further reading.

Comment: Thanks,ChrisW. I firmly believe in simplicity without belittlement or the need for a PhD in Buddhist studies.